# Visual Studio C# library building improperly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I've been developing a large scale project independently for the past two years, and just today I started having problems under the hood.

I have a code library in which I write the majority of my code, and an external project that references the library to implement it.

Suddenly, when I attempt to launch the .exe from the release folder, I get an exception, however when I launch in release mode through visual studio, it works fine. I don't experience this problem in debug mode at all. It appears as though the library is properly rebuilding it's .dll and putting it in the release folder despite this behavior. I've tried everything from messing with properties to completely deleting all trace of the library, adding a new one, and copying only the code files into the fresh project, and I still experience the same behavior.

Comment: Could you provide the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue related to environmental differences between DEV and Production systems.  Chances are very high the Production system does not have the proper pre-requisite dlls on the system.  You can determine the exact root cause of this problem by starting the Fusion log viewer, recreating the problem and reading the log.  It will tell you what DLL is missing.

https://www.google.com/search?q=fusion+log&oq=fusion+log&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1890j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8